# How to allow apache to serve a file written by rsyslogd (selinux)

Tags: apache-httpd, selinux, rsyslog

I have a an application which is run as a systemd service on RHEL7 that makes use of the system journal for logging.  To ease monitoring of this application I have configured `rsyslogd` to write logs from this service (only) to a dedicated log file.

I would now like to serve this log file using `httpd` so that users can easily monitor the application.

The problem I am facing is that no matter how I setup the file contexts it seems `selinux` will prevent me from doing what I want:

- `rsyslog` is allowed to write to `var_log_t`
- `httpd` is allowed to read from `httpd_sys_content_t`

As far as I can tell there is no context that will allow writing by `rsyslogd` and reading from `httpd`.

What can I do to get around this problem?  Will I end up needing to create a custom policy module?

Comment: If the need is simple, write a custom rule, see syslogng/logstash/filebeat

Answer (score 0):

You can check if a boolean exists to allow the access using [`audit2why`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/audit2why), in which case you do not need to create a custom policy module.

If no such boolean exists, to allow apache to read the logs you need to append the policy. With [`audit2allow`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/audit2allow) you can create the policy module directly or create the required rules you can use as template for your module.

First you need to generate the logs containing access violations. To get all the access violations during the normal use, set *httpd_t* to permissive mode. In permissive mode SELinux policy is not enforced for the specified type (*httpd_t*), but logs will be generated as usual:

```
semanage permissive -a httpd_t
```

After you have verified your configuration works and you can access the logs with Apache, turn enforcing mode back on:

```
semanage permissive -d httpd_t
```

Now use `audit2allow` to generate the new module and insert it:

```
audit2allow -a -M apache_logs
semodule -i apache_logs.pp
```

If you want to be sure audit messages only related to *httpd_t* are used for creating the module, *grep* the relevant lines from audit log and use it as input for audit2allow. For example:

```
grep "httpd_t" /var/log/audit/audit.log | audit2allow -M apache_logs
```

If you want to manually verify or modify the rules generated by *audit2allow*, generate the module in source format using `-m` option. You can verify and edit the generated module source if you wish. After you are done, you need to build the module. Steps are demonstrated in the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/audit2allow) example.